# Are events like the Siberian heat wave factored into models of sea ice decline?

Tags: climate-change, arctic, sea-ice

I've been looking at a lot of charts of Arctic Sea Ice lately, wondering when it will be gone, and whether the more extreme predictions are credible.
When scientists come up with a chart that points to around 2040 for sea ice going, do their models include events like the Siberian heat wave ?
Could such a thing render 2040 estimates useless ?
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41558-020-0860-7 may be of interest.

Comment: thanks but, meh, paywall.

Comment: For me it says: "You have full access to this article via FAO Food & Agriculture Organization"
[Download PDF](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41558-020-0860-7.pdf)

Comment: @KeithMcClary Looks like it's seeing an institutional login for you - the names are sometimes odd/wrong though.  Nature usually has non-paywall readcube links at the bottom of articles for sharing: https://rdcu.be/b6dFF

Comment: @Deditos Strange, I don't get access when I use another browser,  but I can download it on [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343298299_Past_perspectives_on_the_present_era_of_abrupt_Arctic_climate_change).

Comment: No it still goes to paywall. Would be nice to my Athens membership back.

Comment: Anyway - Siberian heat waves in the models ?